# iOS expected a expression

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

This is likely not the hardest problem tackled on Stackoverflow, but I can't seem to figure it out...

I got a switch statement and in this switch statement I want a local variable which represent the text field. So I can set it secure. This is the code I use for that:

```
[(UITextField * )[cell.contentView viewWithTag:TABLE_TEXT_FIELD_TAG] setSecureTextEntry:YES]; // Works
```

Now I want to set more properties, hence the need (not really need but good coding principle) of the local variable. I use this:

```
case 1:   
        UITextField *textFieldPassword = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:TABLE_TEXT_FIELD_TAG]; 
        // Error I get: Expected expression
        break;
```

Why does the compiler complains about this?

Comment: add code in {} inside case 1

Comment: Thank you... This was possible lack of sleep ;) Maybe post an actual answer so I can give credits?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212796/objective-c-formatting-style-causes-an-error-in-a-switch-case

Comment: @JayGajjar : post the answer dude so that MouNtant could accept it.

Comment: @nevan king this is not a simular question in the sense that I didn't know the problem was with the switch statement. I thought the problem lied in the way I instantiated the UITextField.

Comment: Antonio will get the correct answer since I want to accept an answer for future reference, even though Jay Gajjar was first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a switch statement is used in a multiple lines brackets should be used.

```
case 1:   {
    UITextField *textFieldPassword = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:TABLE_TEXT_FIELD_TAG]; 
    // Error I get: Expected expression
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
case 1:   
{
        UITextField *textFieldPassword = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:TABLE_TEXT_FIELD_TAG]; 
        // Error I get: Expected expression
        break;
}
```